# What device limits output current such that input voltage is maintained above some limit?

Tags: current, voltage-regulator

I think my problem is that I just don't know the name of this device/circuit, but if someone can provide an outline of how to put one together also, or point me at a device, that'd be a help.

The device I seek is a current limiter, but it is rigged so that output current can take any value so long as the input voltage to the device does not fall below some fixed lower value. In contrast to more familiar current limiters which, well, limit the current to some fixed upper value.

The design intent is to have one power domain for controllers that never falls below X (say, 4V), whilst high-power devices (motors) can be operated freely on the downstream side of the device without fear they will kill the controllers if they draw large transient currents.

Thanks

Comment: That's rather vague. Where does the "large transient current" come from if it doesn't come from the input bus?

Comment: Do you mean you want to _shut off_ the output if the input voltage is too low? That is a common item for battery protection, a "low voltage disconnect", but I don't know whether typical ones operate fast enough for this purpose (and in fact they might be deliberately “slow blow” since the concern is over-discharging rather than instantaneous load conditions).

Comment: I am a bit confused. I think you need to draw some kind of diagram and explain how the voltage behaves at each stage. It sounds like you want the device to reduce load current when input voltage starts to sag, but I am not sure.

Comment: Assuming I understand correctly, I think I need to make sure YOU understand the consequences. If high power devices downstream from your limiter try to use large currents, and the limiter goes into action, the dowstream voltage will crash rapidly toward zero. Is that going to be OK and what you want?

Comment: Dave: draw from the motors, when loaded; Kevin: yes, but gradually, rather than on-off; @mkeith You do understand correctly, and yes I do want the downstream voltage to crash if necessary. If the motors transiently fail, no problem, so long as the controller power domain remains above X.

Comment: It is not exactly what you asked for, but there is such a thing as a current limiting switch. You can google that and see if it might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rereading your question I think you are looking for something like this that is downstream from your logic circuits and before the power circuits.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuwKLY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The top part with R3 is your classical current limiter.

R2, D1 and Q3 will begin to turn off the tail of the current limiter if the input voltage falls too low. The values will be rather soft though since you have no solid reference with a sinking rail.

As with all current limiters of this type there is a significant voltage drop incurred across the R1, Q1 circuit.

Q1 and R1 would of course need to be powerful enough to carry your full load current and worse carry large currents with a higher Vce when it is choking the current.

I do not think I would use this circuit for anything but lower level currents. Further, if you intend on using more than one of these on the same power bus, do not be surprised when they start an oscillation between them.

Ultimately you would be better to fix your load problems and or get bigger supplies.

Comment: Thanks Trevor - I can see that there's a problem here of loading up Q1 with non-negligible VCE, but since I'm only expecting this to be occasional transients perhaps that's not such a biggy. Fix load problems? Easier to do this, in this case. Get bigger supplies? Already the best we can do for the application. Does there need to be a series resistance (R1) in any such design? Feels like there should be a way of doing it where in normal operation (99.9% of the time) the power is only through a transistor that is switched on. But perhaps I'm wrong...

Comment: @RattusExMachina in this case the small resistor R1 is what sets the current limit so it is critical. You may however be better off using something smarter to monitor the voltage and current and have it back off the load drive when need be. Since I don't know what the rest of your system is that is only a suggestion though.

Comment: Maybe something like this but with a TL431 and a PMOS.

Comment: Thanks guys - this gives me a starting point. We'll try something like this out and see if it gets us where we want to be.